# How to display the active image in carousel in my second div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I display in my 2nd div the active image in the carousel?
`

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="image1.jpeg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="image2.jpeg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="image3.jpeg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="image1.jpeg">
</div>
```

`
I'd like to know some tips to do that properly.

Comment: Can you also post the javascript code that you're using?

Comment: I'm just using the bootstrap carousel sir.